# GLP type three filter of order k, amplitude response?

Tags: finite-impulse-response

Given a GLP type three filter of order K, with an amplitude response of |H(theta)|.

I need to show that the number of real and causal FIR filters(identically different) of order K, with the same amplitude response |H(theta)|, is less than or equal to $2^{k-2}$.

My thoughts:

I know that a GLP type three must have at least two zeros on its unit circle, 
which means I have two filters which are identically the same.

meaning that's where the minus two comes from.

**My Question is:** how do I show such a thing mathematically?

how to think about it intuitively?

why is it two to the power..?

Thanks in advance,

Nadav

Comment: WHY ARE WE SCREAMING? Hi Nadav, it's rather unusual to use Caps Lock in titles. Can you use empty lines to structure your question? When you look at the source code edits to your previous question, you'll also learn how to typeset mathematical formulas. Thank you.

Comment: Noted, fixed, thank you!